# Importance of the observation that automorphism preserves the cardinality of any subset?

Tags: group-theory, soft-question

In question 17 of section 1.7 of Dummit and Foote, authors point out that conjugation by an element $g\in G$ is an automorphism that preserves the cardinality of any subset of $G$. Is there an application of this fact in practice? Like, instead of determining the cardinality of a subset, we conjugate it and then determine the cardinality?

Here is the question for context:

> Let $G$ be a group and let $G$ act on itself by left conjugation, so each $g\in G$ maps $G$ to $G$
> by
> $$x\mapsto gxg^{-1}$$•
> For fixed $g\in G$, prove that conjugation by $g$ is an isomorphism from $G$ onto itself (i.e.,
> is an automorphism of $G$ - cf. Exercise 20, Section 6). Deduce that $x$ and $gxg^{-1}$ have
> the same order for all $x$ in $G$ and that for any subset $A$ of $G$, $|A|=|gAg^{-1}|$ (here
> $gAg^{-1}= \{gag^{-1}|a\in A\}$).

Comment: One application that comes to my mind is the following. Let $G$ be a group, $H \le G$ and $g \in G$ such that $g H g^{-1} \le H$. If $G$ is finite, then $g H g^{-1} = H$. If $G$ is infinite, this need not hold.

Comment: Nice!  This answers my questions. Do you mind copy-pasting in the answer?

Comment: With pleasure, thanks! I have added an example for completeness.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\newcommand{\ZZ}{\mathbb{Z}}\newcommand{\Set}[1]{\left\{ #1 \right\}}\DeclareMathOperator{\Aut}{Aut}\newcommand{\Span}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}$One application that comes to my mind is the following. Let $G$
be a group, $H \le G$
and $g \in G$
such that $g H g^{−1} \le H$

- If $H$
  is *finite*, then $g H g^{−1} = H$
- If $H$
  is *infinite*, this need not hold.

An example of the latter phenomenon is the following. Consider the additive group
$$
N = \Set{ \dfrac{a}{2^{n}} : a \in \ZZ}.
$$
Let $\gamma \in \Aut(N)$ be the automorphism of $N$ mapping $x \mapsto 2 x$. Let $G$ be the semidirect product of $N$ by an infinite cyclic group $\Span{g}$, with $g$ acting like $\gamma$ on $N$.

Taking $H = \ZZ \le N \le G$, we see that
$g H g^{-1}$ is the image $2 \ZZ$ of $H$  under $\gamma$, thus a proper subgroup of $H$.